# Algorithm for combining unique while mainting array order

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Currently I'm facing the scenario where I've a multi dimensional array of strings:

```js
var myMultiDimensionalArray = [
  ['foo', 'bar'],
  ['foo', 'baz', 'bar'],
  ['foe', 'bar'],
]
```

I want to combine/merge the array of strings inside `myMultiDimensionalArray` together, filter out duplicates while maintaining the order of the array items.

Thus when processing the `myMultiDimensionalArray` variable, it should result in:

```js
var myProccessedArray = ['foo', 'foe', 'baz', 'bar']
```

However this could also be an possible outcome:

```js
var myProccessedArray = ['foo', 'baz', 'foe', 'bar']
```

Because it's not clear whenever `foe` should be ranked higher or lower then `baz` and vice-versa. When the multi dimensional array includes something like: `['foe', 'baz']` then it would be clear that `foe` is ranked higher then `baz`.

---

Preferably a javascript/typescript solution but a good explanation what to look for and how to achieve such an algorithm should also be enough.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand how you can iterate that 2d array and get those results. Are your results\inputs correct?

Comment: It sounds like topological sorting of a DAG. Is something like `[['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']]` possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linear time, parse the arrays and map each term to the rows it appears in. E.g. 'foo' => [0, 1].

It will always be true that at least one of the terms in front only appears in rows where it is in front (assuming that a valid solution to this is possible).

Repeatedly take a random term from those that only appear in front of their rows and add it to your ordered list.

Here's our map for your example:

```
foo => [0, 1]
foe => [2]
baz => [1]
bar => [1,2,3]

Initial State: Solution = [],
Matrix: 
['foo', 'bar'],
['foo', 'baz', 'bar'],
['foe', 'bar']

'foo' and 'foe' both only appear at the front of their rows. Pick one at random. E.g. 'foe'.
State: Solution = ['foe'],
Matrix: 
['foo', 'bar'],
['foo', 'baz', 'bar'],
['bar']

Now the other of 'foo' and 'foe' only appears at the front of its row. Pick it.
State: Solution = ['foe', 'foo'],
Matrix: 
['bar'],
['baz', 'bar'],
['bar']

Now 'baz' only appears at the front of its row. Pick it.
State: Solution = ['foe', 'foo', 'baz'],
Matrix: 
['bar'],
['bar'],
['bar']

Finally, pick 'bar'. Solution = ['foe', 'foo', 'baz', 'bar']
```

Comment: Interesting approach, unfortunately it doesn't yield one of the expected results. Thus this algorithm wouldn't work for the use case in question.

Comment: @luukvhoudt This yields a random result from all possible results. If you need it to yield all possible results then comment and I can modify it to do so. In essence, each place where I pick a valid choice at random, the algorithm would change to iterating through all possibilities.

Comment: No it's fine, no modifications are needed. After all I realized that your result is also correct. I didn't think about it before that the row `['foe', 'bar']` is lacking `foo` thus it's not clear if `foe` is before or after `foo`. The only requirement it has is that it is ranked before `bar`.